# The number of subsets in a Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If X has $n$ elements then $\mathcal P$(X) has $2^n$ elements. Let X = {x,y,z}. By regularity, x≠{x}, and both x and {x} are subsets because everything is a set in axiomatic set theory. With this in mind, I'm struggling to understand why $\mathcal P$(X)={{},{x},{y},{z},{x,y},{x,z},{y,z},{x,y,z}} and not {{},x,y,z,{x},{y},{z},{x,y},{y,z},{x,z},{x,y,z}} unless we define x,y,z to be urelements. Is $\mathcal P$={{},{x},{y},{z},{x,y},{x,z},{y,z},{x,y,z}} because x, y, z are subsets that contain no elements and are therefore collectively represented by the empty set? Thanks for your time and help

Comment: I don't understand. How can $x$ be a subset of anything if $x$ is not a set? On the other hand, $\{x\}$ is indeed a subset of $\mathcal{P}$...

Comment: How is x not a set in axiomatic set theory? I thought that axiomatic set theory precludes urelements

Comment: It well could be that all elements here (including $x$) are subsets of some global set $\Omega$, but that does not alter the reality: if $X = \{x,y,z\}$ then $\{x\} \subset X$ but $x \not \subset X$.

Comment: By foundation, if $x \subset X$ here, then $x \subset \{y,\,z\}$, so $x$ is one of $\varnothing,\, \{y\},\,\{z\},\,\{y,\,z\}$, so it's already listed in the first list.

Comment: @DanielFischer how does foundation imply "if x⊂X here, then x⊂{y,z}?" Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $X$ has three elements, $x,\, y,\, z$. $x \in x$ is forbidden by foundation, so the only elements $x$ can have are $y$ and $z$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that in set theory we often take the case where there are no urelements, and everything is a set, but that doesn't mean that $x\in y$ implies $x\subseteq y$.

Consider the set $\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$. It's a singleton, despite the fact that its element is a set. So it only has two subsets, $\varnothing$ and itself. So its power set would consist of these two elements. And despite the fact that $\varnothing$ is an element of an element of this set, it is not an element of the the set itself.

Comment: Thank you for another very lucid response. So x can be a set and x∈X but x may be entirely comprised of elements that are not elements of X. If this is the case, x is not a subset of X. Correct?

Comment: @user84815: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is an element of $A$, not a subset of $A$, and "a set of all subsets" must contain only subsets, so your expression $\mathcal P(A)=\{\emptyset,x,y,z,\{x\},\{y\},\{z\},\{x,y\},\{y,z\},\{x,z\},\{x,y,z\}\} $ doesn't have much sence.

Comment: I thought there were no urelements in axiomatic set theory. I.e., no elements that are not sets.

Comment: @user84815 If I recall correctly, axiomatic set theory doesn't need them, and there're constructions which use them and which don't. Set theory doesn't avoid them. And, as I undetstand things, urelements or not, this is irrelevent for the problem. $x\in A$, $x\not\subset A$.

Comment: Oh, so while axiomatic set theory doesn't need urelements, we can construct sets that contain urelements using axiomatic set theory?

Comment: @user84815 If you take a look at wiki article on urelements, there're citations about axiomatic constructions with urelements